# Создать запрос, отображающий бригады, в которых ВСЕ рабочие имеют высокую квалификацию

Tags: sql, запрос

Помогите пожалуйста.

Есть таблица с рабочими (в ней так же указаны id их бригад).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также есть их квалификация.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно вывести бригады, у которых абсолютно все рабочие с высшей квалификацией.
Если хотя бы один рабочий с какой-то другой квалификацией, то всю бригаду выводить не нужно.

Я пытался что-то сделать но оно работает не правильно)

```
select Квалификация,Номер_бригады, Код_рабочего
from Вакансии v1 INNER JOIN Квалификация k1 ON 
v1.Код_специальности = k1.Код_специальности
where 
exists (select * from Вакансии v2 INNER JOIN Квалификация k2 ON 
v2.Код_специальности = k2.Код_специальности where (k2.Квалификация like '%Высшая%') 
and (k2.Код_рабочего = k1.Код_рабочего) 
and (v2.Номер_бригады = v1.Номер_бригады))
```

Comment: Я бы наоборот сделал `WHERE NOT EXISTS` и там выбрал бы бригаду с таким же `id` и квалификацией `NOT LIKE %Высшая%`

Comment: Помогло. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Тогда оформлю в виде ответа )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте наоборот - поставьте условие `WHERE NOT EXISTS` и там выберите вакансии с бригадой с таким же `id` и с квалификацией рабочего `NOT LIKE %Высшая%`. Таким образом в вашей выборке останутся только бригады, где нет рабочих с другой квалификацией, чем высшая.